# Restore tarsnap archive into specific folder

Tags: backup, restore

I'm using [tarsnap](https://www.tarsnap.com/) for backups, and it is working fine. However, to test a backup, I would like to restore it but without overwriting the current version of the files. It would thus make sense to extract the backup to a folder separate to the source folder of the backup. Can tarsnap do this?

Answer (score 5):

From the manpage:

```
 -C directory
         (c and x modes only) In c mode, this changes the directory before adding the following files.  In x mode, change directories after opening the archive but before
         extracting entries from the archive.
```

So, `tarsnap -f imagename -C output-dir` will extract `imagename` into `output-dir`.